# Can't Even Sit Down

Tags: knowledge, steganography

So I just re-watched a fun movie from a few years ago.

> tart con arc host

What was the name of the movie?

Comment: Does this involve any non-English words?

Comment: @Carley nope, it doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The movie you watched from a few years ago was:

> [Sing](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3470600/)

Rationale:

> The title is made up of the missing first letters from the words... start, icon, narc, and ghost.

The Title:

> Is a reference to "I'm Still Standing", a song by Elton John that's performed in the movie.

Comment: That's it! Any ideas on the title?

Comment: The only quote that came to mind didn't feel appropriate from The Big Lebowski... :)

Comment: Well that flew over my head XD. The title's an oblique reference to the Elton John song in the movie.

Answer (score -1):

Answer could be...

> Raiders of the Lost Arc

Explanation:

> Based on the word..arc...host..lost..the name popped in my head.

Comment: please explain your approach to this answer. thanks and happy puzzling ;)

Comment: Based on the word..arc...host..lost..the name popped in my head.