# Crazy for revenge

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking

@Brandon_J recently asked us in [Can't Even Sit Down](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83774/cant-even-sit-down) to identify a movie based on the words

> tart con arc host

I've also been to see a fun movie from a few years ago, just a short one

> buck con art tart

What movie did I see?

**Hint**

> Four words

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, this one:

> [VIPs](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1235548/)

Because

> if it follows the same gimmick as Brandon_J's, we can find
>  **v**buck **i**con  **p**art  **s**tart
>
>  You did say a short one, so maybe you meant [this comedy short](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2023807/?ref_=adv_li_tt),
>  but that doesn't seem like a film you'd be particularly likely to have seen to me.
>  It might also be a film named VETS (as **e**con and **t**art are things), but I don't see one.

Comment: Well, a comedy short can be as much fun as a full-length film. But it’s none of those you suggested (it would be boring to use the same puzzle method twice!)

Answer (score 0):

maybe the comedy was:

> The Con Is On

because:

> the "con" is still on, moreover exactly the same place (the others changed) and you are "heisting"(stealing) the idea too, (I wouldn`t be surprised if you were a con-artist as well)

unfortunately neither a short movie, nor few years ago, so this one doesn`t fit, but I arbitrarily consider this a funny option ;)